# Bind ListBox selected color to SelectedItem's property

Tags: wpf, xaml, data-binding, windows-8

I have a `ListBox` control bound to an `ObservableCollection<ToDoCategory>` as `ItemsSource="{Binding Categories}`. Inside the `ToDoCategory` there are `CategoryName` and `CategoryColor` (both strings). `CategoryName` is bound inside the `ItemTemplate`. Now, what I would like to do is to change the color of category selected in the `ListBox` based on `CategoryColor`. I already have string to brush `IValueConverter` which returns `SolidColorBrush` for string. It is also correctly defined in the page resources. I know I need to change `ItemContainerStyle`. Currently, I have something like this:

```
<Style x:Key="CategoryListBoxContainerStyle" TargetType="ListBoxItem">
Setter Property="Template">
    <Setter.Value>
        <ControlTemplate TargetType="ListBoxItem">
            <Border...>
            <VisualStateManager.VisualStateGroups>
                <VisualState x:Name="Selected">
                    <Storyboard>
                        <ObjectAnimationUsingKeyFrames Storyboard.TargetProperty="Background" Storyboard.TargetName="InnerGrid">
                            <DiscreteObjectKeyFrame KeyTime="0" Value="{Binding CategoryColor, Converter=StringToBrushConverter}"/>
                        </ObjectAnimationUsingKeyFrames>
                        <ObjectAnimationUsingKeyFrames Storyboard.TargetProperty="Foreground" Storyboard.TargetName="ContentPresenter">
                            <DiscreteObjectKeyFrame KeyTime="0" Value="{StaticResource ListBoxItemSelectedForegroundThemeBrush}"/>
                        </ObjectAnimationUsingKeyFrames>
                    </Storyboard>
                </VisualState>
                .
                .
                .
</style>
```

This doesn't work. How do I bind the Background of the InnerGrid to `CategoryColor` from the `ToDoCategory`?

Comment: It seems like you should be working with the style or template, not a VisualState.

Comment: @Rhyous The VisualState is part of ItemContainer template. See the edit!

Comment: See if you can get the Background of the Selected property to even go to a static color.  ListBox uses Style.Resources for forground and background.   http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7059526/set-background-color-for-selected-items-in-a-listbox