# WPF: Horizontally aligned collection with items of uniform width

Tags: wpf, itemtemplate

I have a variable number of items bound from view model that need to be displayed horizontally and be selectable.
Each item is represented by a text, these texts vary in length. When I use a list view with a StackPanel with horizontal orientation as its ItemTemplate, the items are only as wide as the text inside. 
Is there a way to make them all the same size, meaning the size of the widest one? Ideally without some complex codebehind, using item templates and such?
Note: I can't set some arbitrary minimum width, because I don't know what length the texts can ultimately have (different languages etc)

Comment: Can you do something like 'Width="1*"' for each item?

Comment: Not sure what you mean by that. Width on a TexBlock doesn't support things like "1*'. If you meant having a grid with a column definition, I just tried that. Doesn't do anything. But even if I somehow got that to work, I think that would stretch my items to maximum width available which is not at all what I want.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

you can use `ListBox` which has selection support with `UniformGrid` as ItemsPanel. UniformGrid will allocate equal space for each element

```
<ListBox>
    <ListBox.ItemsPanel>
        <ItemsPanelTemplate>
            <UniformGrid Rows="1"/>
        </ItemsPanelTemplate>
    </ListBox.ItemsPanel>

    <ListBox.ItemTemplate>
        <DataTemplate>
            <Label Content="{Binding}"/>
        </DataTemplate>
    </ListBox.ItemTemplate>
</ListBox>
```

example

[image: uniform]

Comment: While that's working, I'm having trouble adding a border between the items, and changing the default background color of a selected item. Can you help me out?

Comment: @Shaggydog, check [this Q+A](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7059526/set-background-color-for-selected-items-in-a-listbox) for color setting example. separator: I would start by adding side border to Label (`Label BorderThickness="1,0" BorderBrush="Red"`) or Border element around Label. If didn't look nice, i would try with custom ListBoxItem Template. I'm without IDE at the moment so if you need more detailed help regarding your issue I suggest to ask a new question.