# How to set background color of menuitem

Tags: wpf

I have developed WPF application which contains the menuitem.
I set background color to these menuitem using the following code-

```
<MenuItem Header="_Main"  >

            <MenuItem Header=" _Daily Expences">
                <MenuItem.Background >
                    <LinearGradientBrush StartPoint="0,0.5" EndPoint="1,0.5">
                        <LinearGradientBrush.GradientStops>
                            <GradientStop Offset="0" Color="DeepSkyBlue"  />
                            <GradientStop Offset="1" Color="DarkOliveGreen"   />
                        </LinearGradientBrush.GradientStops>
                    </LinearGradientBrush>
                </MenuItem.Background>
            </MenuItem>
         <Separator ></Separator>
            <MenuItem Header=" _Business">
               <MenuItem.Background >
                    <LinearGradientBrush StartPoint="0,0.5" EndPoint="1,0.5">
                        <LinearGradientBrush.GradientStops>
                            <GradientStop Offset="0" Color="DeepSkyBlue"  />
                            <GradientStop Offset="1" Color="DarkOliveGreen"   />
                        </LinearGradientBrush.GradientStops>
                    </LinearGradientBrush>
                </MenuItem.Background>
            </MenuItem>
        </MenuItem>
```

When i run the application it shows the color which i set, but the background color for this menu list is still gray when i focus the cursor on the menuitem.
Please help me to solve this problem.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think you should use `MenuItem.ItemContainerStyle`

take a look at the answer here (for me it should be the same problem):
[changing background color of container when textbox is in focus](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2138200/wpf-change-background-color-for-selected-listbox-item)