# WPF Changing ListboxItem Highlight Color when Selected

Tags: wpf, background-color, listboxitem

I've got a problem with setting the `HighlightBrushKey` of a `SelectedItem` of a `Listbox` in WPF. My intention was to set the color of an Item depending on a given Boolean value, lying in code.

I've tried following steps:

- Implementing a Converter, checking the boolean and returning the right color.

  Example:

  ```
  <ribbon:RibbonWindow.Resources>
    <l:WindowControl x:Key="ListBoxItemBackgroundConverter" />
      <Style x:Key="listBoxStyle" TargetType="{x:Type ListBoxItem}">
        <Style.Resources>
          <SolidColorBrush x:Key="{x:Static SystemColors.HighlightBrushKey}" Color="{Binding Source={x:Static SystemColors.HighlightBrushKey}, Converter={StaticResource ListBoxItemBackgroundConverter}}"/>
          <SolidColorBrush x:Key="{x:Static SystemColors.ControlBrushKey}" Color="{Binding Source={x:Static SystemColors.ControlBrushKey}, Converter={StaticResource ListBoxItemBackgroundConverter}}"/>
        </Style.Resources>
      </Style>
  </ribbon:RibbonWindow.Resources>
  ```

  The problem here was that the Convert method was called only once, but I need the Converter to be called every time I select an item and checking the Boolean. Like a Trigger, but with the "`HighlightBrushKey`".

  Converter:

  ```
  public object Convert(object value, Type targetType,
                        object parameter, CultureInfo culture)
  {
     if(currentField == null)
        return Brushes.Yellow;
     if (currentField.Save)
        return Brushes.LightGreen;
     else
        return Brushes.Yellow;
  }
  ```
- My next idea was setting "`HighlightBrushKey`" to "`Transparent`" and changing the `item.Background` manually in code. The Problem here was that my items became white and the Background Color could not be seen

  Example:

  ```
  <ListBox.Resources>
      <SolidColorBrush x:Key="{x:Static SystemColors.HighlightBrushKey}" Color="Transparent" />
      <SolidColorBrush x:Key="{x:Static SystemColors.HighlightTextBrushKey}" Color="Black" />
      <SolidColorBrush x:Key="{x:Static SystemColors.ControlBrushKey}" Color="Transparent" />
  </ListBox.Resources>
  ```

Thanks in Advance! :)

Comment: Nice first question Andy, well constructed with precise examples of exactly what you were trying to highlight! +1

Comment: @Andy What is currentField1 in your converter? How are you getting this in Converter? Can you try binding to `currentField `(i.e. YourViewModelProperty) in the style invisible provided.

Comment: currentField is an object.
Class name is Field and is has a Boolean Property named "Save".
how can i bind to it in XAML?

Comment: Sounds like you need a multivalueconverter which checks IsSelected and your bool

Answer (score 1):

```
<Style x:Key="listBoxStyle" TargetType="{x:Type ListBox}">
    <Style.Resources>
         <!-- Background of selected item when focussed -->
         <SolidColorBrush x:Key="{x:Static SystemColors.HighlightBrushKey}" Color="Red" />
         <!-- Background of selected item when not focussed -->
         <SolidColorBrush x:Key="{x:Static SystemColors.ControlBrushKey}" Color="Green" />
    </Style.Resources>
</Style>

<ListBox Style="{StaticResource listBoxStyle}">
</ListBox>
```

Comment: thanks for your answer, but this doesnt solve my problem. I know these lines, but I have an existing dependency between the color (your example: color="Red") and an Boolean value currentField.Save, an object in runtime. If it is false, then the color should be yellow and if it is true, the color should be green.

Comment: This no longer applies for Windows-8 which uses static colors in the ControlTemplate triggers. Consider https://stackoverflow.com/a/62714750/417939 instead.

Answer (score 0):

If you wish to disable the highlighting when a listboxitem is selected or mouse over, you can use the below code.

```
<Style TargetType="ListBoxItem" x:Key="ListBoxItemStyle">
    <Setter Property="IsSelected" Value="{Binding Content.IsSelected, Mode=TwoWay, RelativeSource={RelativeSource Self}}"/>
    <Setter Property="Template">
        <Setter.Value>
            <ControlTemplate TargetType="ListBoxItem">
                <ContentPresenter/>
            </ControlTemplate>
        </Setter.Value>
    </Setter>
</Style>

<ListBox ItemContainerStyle="{StaticResource ListBoxItemStyle}"/>
```