# Change Selection Color of ListBoxItem in WPF

Tags: wpf, xaml, wpf-style

Sorry that my question is redundant for instance with these ones:

- [WPF Changing ListboxItem Highlight Color when Selected](https://stackoverflow.com/q/11152982/13439267)
- [Why can't I set the background color of a selected ListBoxItem in WPF?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/491293/13439267)

but for whatever reason neither changing the ItemContainerStyle, nor overriding the SystemColors works for me. Can someone tell me what I have to change in this XAML code to change the background color of selected ListBoxItems (or more precisely the ItemsContainer around them) to red? All the other colors that I set are assigned correctly.

```
<ListBox>
    <ListBox.Resources>
        <SolidColorBrush x:Key="{x:Static SystemColors.HighlightColorKey}" Color="Red" />
        <SolidColorBrush x:Key="{x:Static SystemColors.HighlightBrushKey}" Color="Red" />
        <SolidColorBrush x:Key="{x:Static SystemColors.ControlBrushKey}" Color="Red" />
        <SolidColorBrush x:Key="{x:Static SystemColors.InactiveSelectionHighlightBrushKey }" Color="Red" />
    </ListBox.Resources>

    <ListBox.ItemContainerStyle>
        <Style TargetType="{x:Type ListBoxItem}">
            <Setter Property="Foreground" Value="HotPink"/>
            <Setter Property="Background" Value="Yellow"/>
            <Setter Property="Margin" Value="2"/>
            <Style.Triggers>
                <Trigger Property="IsSelected" Value="True">
                    <Setter Property="Foreground" Value="Green"/>
                    <Setter Property="Background" Value="Red"/>
                </Trigger>
                <Trigger Property="IsFocused" Value="True">
                    <Setter Property="Foreground" Value="Green"/>
                    <Setter Property="Background" Value="Red"/>
                </Trigger>
            </Style.Triggers>
        </Style>
    </ListBox.ItemContainerStyle>

    <ListBox.ItemTemplate>
        <DataTemplate>
            <TextBlock Text="{Binding}"/>
        </DataTemplate>
    </ListBox.ItemTemplate>

    <ListBoxItem>A</ListBoxItem>
    <ListBoxItem>B</ListBoxItem>
    <ListBoxItem>C</ListBoxItem>
    <ListBoxItem>D</ListBoxItem>
</ListBox>
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Both approaches do not work because:

- The default control templates may not necessarily use the system colors.
- The default control template triggers take [precedence](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/desktop/wpf/advanced/dependency-property-value-precedence?view=netframeworkdesktop-4.8#dependency-property-setting-precedence-list) over your style setters.

You have to [extract the default style](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8825030/how-to-extract-default-control-template-in-visual-studio) and control template e.g. by using Visual Studio or Blend in order to have a working base to start from. Adapt the colors in the styles an control template triggers.

```
<SolidColorBrush x:Key="Item.MouseOver.Background"
                 Color="#1F26A0DA" />
<SolidColorBrush x:Key="Item.MouseOver.Border"
                 Color="#a826A0Da" />
<SolidColorBrush x:Key="Item.SelectedActive.Background"
                 Color="#3D26A0DA" />
<SolidColorBrush x:Key="Item.SelectedActive.Border"
                 Color="#FF26A0DA" />
<SolidColorBrush x:Key="Item.SelectedInactive.Background"
                 Color="#3DDADADA" />
<SolidColorBrush x:Key="Item.SelectedInactive.Border"
                 Color="#FFDADADA" />
<Style x:Key="FocusVisual">
   <Setter Property="Control.Template">
      <Setter.Value>
         <ControlTemplate>
            <Rectangle Margin="2"
                       StrokeDashArray="1 2"
                       SnapsToDevicePixels="true"
                       StrokeThickness="1"
                       Stroke="{DynamicResource {x:Static SystemColors.ControlTextBrushKey}}" />
         </ControlTemplate>
      </Setter.Value>
   </Setter>
</Style>
<Style x:Key="ListBoxItemStyle"
       TargetType="{x:Type ListBoxItem}">
   <Setter Property="SnapsToDevicePixels"
           Value="True" />
   <Setter Property="Padding"
           Value="4,1" />
   <Setter Property="HorizontalContentAlignment"
           Value="{Binding HorizontalContentAlignment, RelativeSource={RelativeSource AncestorType={x:Type ItemsControl}}}" />
   <Setter Property="VerticalContentAlignment"
           Value="{Binding VerticalContentAlignment, RelativeSource={RelativeSource AncestorType={x:Type ItemsControl}}}" />
   <Setter Property="Background"
           Value="Transparent" />
   <Setter Property="BorderBrush"
           Value="Transparent" />
   <Setter Property="BorderThickness"
           Value="1" />
   <Setter Property="FocusVisualStyle"
           Value="{StaticResource FocusVisual}" />
   <Setter Property="Template">
      <Setter.Value>
         <ControlTemplate TargetType="{x:Type ListBoxItem}">
            <Border x:Name="Bd"
                    Background="{TemplateBinding Background}"
                    BorderThickness="{TemplateBinding BorderThickness}"
                    BorderBrush="{TemplateBinding BorderBrush}"
                    Padding="{TemplateBinding Padding}"
                    SnapsToDevicePixels="true">
               <ContentPresenter HorizontalAlignment="{TemplateBinding HorizontalContentAlignment}"
                                 SnapsToDevicePixels="{TemplateBinding SnapsToDevicePixels}"
                                 VerticalAlignment="{TemplateBinding VerticalContentAlignment}" />
            </Border>
            <ControlTemplate.Triggers>
               <MultiTrigger>
                  <MultiTrigger.Conditions>
                     <Condition Property="IsMouseOver"
                                Value="True" />
                  </MultiTrigger.Conditions>
                  <Setter Property="Background"
                          TargetName="Bd"
                          Value="{StaticResource Item.MouseOver.Background}" />
                  <Setter Property="BorderBrush"
                          TargetName="Bd"
                          Value="{StaticResource Item.MouseOver.Border}" />
               </MultiTrigger>
               <MultiTrigger>
                  <MultiTrigger.Conditions>
                     <Condition Property="Selector.IsSelectionActive"
                                Value="False" />
                     <Condition Property="IsSelected"
                                Value="True" />
                  </MultiTrigger.Conditions>
                  <Setter Property="Background"
                          TargetName="Bd"
                          Value="{StaticResource Item.SelectedInactive.Background}" />
                  <Setter Property="BorderBrush"
                          TargetName="Bd"
                          Value="{StaticResource Item.SelectedInactive.Border}" />
               </MultiTrigger>
               <MultiTrigger>
                  <MultiTrigger.Conditions>
                     <Condition Property="Selector.IsSelectionActive"
                                Value="True" />
                     <Condition Property="IsSelected"
                                Value="True" />
                  </MultiTrigger.Conditions>
                  <Setter Property="Background"
                          TargetName="Bd"
                          Value="{StaticResource Item.SelectedActive.Background}" />
                  <Setter Property="BorderBrush"
                          TargetName="Bd"
                          Value="{StaticResource Item.SelectedActive.Border}" />
               </MultiTrigger>
               <Trigger Property="IsEnabled"
                        Value="False">
                  <Setter Property="TextElement.Foreground"
                          TargetName="Bd"
                          Value="{DynamicResource {x:Static SystemColors.GrayTextBrushKey}}" />
               </Trigger>
            </ControlTemplate.Triggers>
         </ControlTemplate>
      </Setter.Value>
   </Setter>
</Style>
```

Then use the style in your `ListBox` by explicitly referencing it or make it an implicit style style by omitting the `x:Key`, so it will be applied to all `ListBoxItem`s in scope.

```
<ListBox ItemContainerStyle="{StaticResource ListBoxItemStyle}">
```

Comment: Thank you, this works for me! However, I am surprised that one has to use such an approach for a task that looks relatively simple.