# Changing entire row color of List Box

Tags: wpf

So I've been trying for several hours to find a solution to my problem. On the internet we can find a method that is said to work ([link](http://blogs.msdn.com/b/wpfsdk/archive/2007/08/31/specifying-the-selection-color-content-alignment-and-background-color-for-items-in-a-listbox.aspx)).

But after trying it, whenever I select one entry of my listbox only the text turns Blue (via the Foreground property) but the row isn't colored Red. Do you have any idea on what I am doing wrong ?

```
<Style x:Key="BPFStandardListBoxItem" TargetType="{x:Type ListBoxItem}">
    <Style.Resources>
        <SolidColorBrush x:Key="{x:Static SystemColors.HighlightBrushKey}" Color="Red"/>
        <SolidColorBrush x:Key="{x:Static SystemColors.ControlBrushKey}" Color="Purple"/>
    </Style.Resources>
    <Setter Property="Control.Template">
        <Setter.Value>
            <ControlTemplate TargetType="{x:Type ListBoxItem}">
                <Border Name="Border" Padding="2" SnapsToDevicePixels="true">
                    <ContentPresenter />
                </Border>
                <ControlTemplate.Triggers>
                    <Trigger Property="IsSelected" Value="True">
                        <Setter Property="Foreground" Value="Blue" />
                    </Trigger>
                    <Trigger Property="IsMouseOver" Value="True">
                        <Setter Property="Cursor" Value="Hand" />
                    </Trigger>
                </ControlTemplate.Triggers>
            </ControlTemplate>
        </Setter.Value>
    </Setter> 
</Style>
```

Comment: Looks correct to me but maybe try and set it directly on the ListBoxItems.  See may answer on this link  http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2138200/wpf-change-background-color-for-selected-listbox-item/6835305#6835305

Comment: Hm, I'm not sure if I get your point. Am I not already trying to set it directly on the ListBoxItem as this is the TargetType of my BPFStandardListBoxItem?

Comment: Then don't try it. If you cannot see the difference in that syntax then I can't help you.

Comment: Does it work to set the `ListBox.ItemTemplate` instead of overwriting the `ListBoxItem.Template`? I suspect [RV1987 is correct](http://stackoverflow.com/a/13051622/302677) in that you're missing something that exists in the default template.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Since you have `override` the `default template` of listboxItem, so in the process you must have `broken` something, may be some triggers or some default properties since that got overriden completly by your template.

What you are trying to achieve can be achieved without overriding the template like this (Use brush `HighlightTextBrushKey` to set foreground) -

```
<Style x:Key="BPFStandardListBoxItem" TargetType="{x:Type ListBoxItem}">
   <Style.Resources>
      <SolidColorBrush x:Key="{x:Static SystemColors.HighlightBrushKey}"
                       Color="Red"/>
      <SolidColorBrush x:Key="{x:Static SystemColors.HighlightTextBrushKey}" 
                       Color="Blue"/>
      <SolidColorBrush x:Key="{x:Static SystemColors.ControlBrushKey}"
                       Color="Purple"/>
   </Style.Resources>
   <Style.Triggers>
       <Trigger Property="IsMouseOver" Value="True">
           <Setter Property="Cursor" Value="Hand" />
       </Trigger>
    </Style.Triggers>
</Style>
```

Comment: Indeed, this works. Thanks. The problem was from the control Template then !

Answer (score -1):

Hmm, I'm not sure - I've never done it that way before - you could always try setting the borders background on a trigger

..something like

```
 <Trigger Property="IsSelected" Value="true">
                <Setter TargetName="Border" Property="Background"
                     Value="Red"/>
   </Trigger>
```

More information can be found here http://blogs.vbcity.com/xtab/archive/2009/06/29/9344.aspx

Comment: According to StackOverflow and the link I provide in my post,  SystemColors.HighlightBrushKey overriding should change it to red ;) You should read the link, it is stated that doing what you do doesn't work