# Change color of selected items in listbox

Tags: c#, wpf, listbox

Currently when an item is selected (but the control is not) the item is in a very light grey (almost not visible) - this happens when I load my window and programatically set the SelectedItems (restore what the user had done) - until you actually CLICK on an item the selections are pretty much not visible.

So I want to change the color of a SELECTED ITEM in the ListBox ... this is what I have today:

```
        <ListBox Name="lbDates" SelectionMode="Multiple"
                 ItemsSource="{Binding Days}"
                 SelectedItem="{Binding Path=SelectedDays, Mode=TwoWay}">
        </ListBox>
```

Comment: http://joshsmithonwpf.wordpress.com/2007/07/30/customizing-the-selected-item-in-a-listbox/

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2138200/change-background-color-for-selected-listbox-item

Answer (score 0):

you can create a style for ListBoxItem and apply triggers on it

```
    <Style x:Key="ListboxItemStyle" TargetType="{x:Type ListBoxItem}">
    <Style.Triggers>
    <Trigger Property="IsSelected" Value="true>
    <Setter Property="Background" Value="#E8EbEE" />
    </Trigger>
    </Style.Triggers>
    </Style>
```

and then apply it to list box style

```
 <Style x:Key="ListBoxStyle" TargetType="{x:Type ListBox}">
    <Setter Property="ItemContainerStyle" Value="{StaticResource ListboxItemStyle}" />
  </Style>
```