# Why does my list view item have a shadow on half of it?

Tags: c#, wpf, wpf-controls

I have built a WPF ListView. This list view works properly and loads data but I am having a styling problem.

[image: ListViewItem]

So in my XAML Code I have this setup.

```
<Style TargetType="ListViewItem">
  <Style.Triggers>
    <Trigger Property="IsSelected" Value="True">
      <Setter Property="Background" Value="Transparent" />
      <Setter Property="BorderBrush" Value="Transparent" />
    </Trigger>
    <Trigger Property="IsMouseOver" Value="True">
      <Setter Property="Background" Value="Transparent" />
      <Setter Property="BorderBrush" Value="Transparent" />
    </Trigger>
  </Style.Triggers>
</Style>
```

I am trying to remove everything off the background of the item itself. Notice how half the item has a lighter shade of gray on the top? I have yet to be able to figure out how to remove that top half shade of the ListViewItem itself.

And I am trying to target both IsMouseOver and IsSelected for removing the top half light gray shade color off the item. I just want the background to be completely transparent. The borders around the item are just fine.

Comment: That shadow is because a style is defined somewhere.  Style is a different with ListView.  http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2138200/change-background-color-for-selected-listbox-item/6835305#6835305

Answer (score 1):

Try setting them to null instead:

```
    <Style TargetType="ListViewItem">
        <Style.Triggers>
            <Trigger Property="IsSelected" Value="True">
                <Setter Property="Background" Value="{x:Null}" />
                <Setter Property="BorderBrush" Value="{x:Null}" />
            </Trigger>
            <Trigger Property="IsMouseOver" Value="True">
                <Setter Property="Background" Value="{x:Null}" />
                <Setter Property="BorderBrush" Value="{x:Null}" />
            </Trigger>
        </Style.Triggers>
    </Style>
```

**EDIT:**

That style (which is like a gloss effect) comes when using a GridView, which you are probably using as your ListView's View.  Is there any reason you can't use a ListBox?

Comment: That actually gives me the same effect. Also to note, there is a huge performance issue with setting it to null. If you hover the mouse right over the bottom of the item it will start to flicker, causing %50 cpu usage. As with Transparent the flickering doesn't exist. Just as a side note to anyone in the future.

Comment: I have not actually looked at using a ListBox. I do have columns in the GridView. Does ListBox support columns?

Comment: I'm sorry, I missed that you were using columns.  It is technically achievable using a custom template, but may be more hassle than it's worth.