# How to select only a line shape instead of selecting a big square

Tags: wpf, xaml, listview, selecteditem

I'm working on a `WPF` project that has a `ListBox` bound to a collection. This `ListBox` shows the elements in a canvas since these elements are `ellipses` and `lines`.

I am developing an application where I can draw entities (`ellipses`) and connectors (`lines`). That's already working.

I also want to be able to select either a `ellipse` or a `line` which I can already do it, since this capability is provided by the `ListBox`. However, when I select a line, **the selected line looks like an ugly big blue square!**

**Is there a way to select only the pure line?**

Here is how my current ListBox implementation looks like:

```
<ListBox ItemsSource="{Binding Elements}" >            
    <ItemsControl.ItemContainerStyle>
        <Style>
            <Style.Resources>
                <SolidColorBrush x:Key="{x:Static SystemColors.HighlightBrushKey}"
                         Color="Transparent"/>
            </Style.Resources>
            <Setter Property="Canvas.Left" Value="{Binding CanvasLeft}" />
            <Setter Property="Canvas.Top" Value="{Binding CanvasTop}" />
            <Setter Property="Panel.ZIndex" Value="{Binding ZIndex, Mode=TwoWay}" />
        </Style>
    </ItemsControl.ItemContainerStyle>
    <ItemsControl.Resources>
        <DataTemplate DataType="{x:Type vm:EntityViewModel}" >
            <Viewbox>
                <Grid>
                    <Ellipse myb:DraggableBehavior.IsDraggingEnabled="True"
                            Stroke="Black" 
                            Width="{Binding ShapeWidth, Mode=TwoWay}" 
                            Height="{Binding ShapeHeight, Mode=TwoWay}" 
                            Canvas.Left="{Binding X1, Mode=TwoWay}"
                            Canvas.Top="{Binding Y1, Mode=TwoWay}"
                            Fill="{Binding Background}" 
                            Panel.ZIndex="{Binding ZIndex, Mode=TwoWay}" >
                    </Ellipse>
                    <TextBlock Text="{Binding StatePropertiesViewModel.Name}"
                           HorizontalAlignment="Center"  
                           TextAlignment="Center" 
                           VerticalAlignment="Center" />
                </Grid>
            </Viewbox>
        </DataTemplate>
        <DataTemplate DataType="{x:Type vm:LineViewModel}" >
            <Line X1="{Binding X1, Mode=TwoWay}"
                  Y1="{Binding Y1, Mode=TwoWay}"
                  X2="{Binding X2, Mode=TwoWay}"
                  Y2="{Binding Y2, Mode=TwoWay}"
                  Stroke="{Binding Color, Mode=TwoWay}"
                  StrokeThickness="{Binding Thickness, Mode=TwoWay}"
                  Panel.ZIndex="{Binding ZIndex, Mode=TwoWay}"
                  />
        </DataTemplate>
    </ItemsControl.Resources>
    <ItemsControl.ItemsPanel>
        <ItemsPanelTemplate>
            <Canvas />
        </ItemsPanelTemplate>
    </ItemsControl.ItemsPanel>            
</ListBox>
```

**Update**

After following @AbhinavSharma's advice:

```
    <Style.Resources>
        <SolidColorBrush x:Key="{x:Static SystemColors.HighlightBrushKey}"
                         Color="Transparent"/>
    </Style.Resources>
```

It seemed that the blue square selection area is not visible now, it looks better. However, it is still there because, for example, if I have a `Line` shape over an `Ellipse`, I cannot select the ellipse since the invisible selected Line area is still there. i.e. what I get selected when clicking on it is the line, not the ellipse. So, **is there a way to reduce the selection area just to the area of the shape itself?**

Thanks in advance.

Comment: I Think " ugly big blue square!" is  default template of SelectedItem of listbox .Have you tried changing the template for the selected item.
[ListBox `s ItemContainerStyle](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2138200/change-background-color-for-selected-listbox-item) might help you.

Comment: @AbhinavSharma i didn't know about that, could you point me in the right direction?

Comment: have you gone through the link.Was it helpfull?

Comment: Try setting in Itemcontrainer style

<SolidColorBrush x:Key="{x:Static SystemColors.HighlightBrushKey}"
                             Color="Transparent"/>

Comment: @AbhinavSharma Thanks for you reply. It seemed to work regarding the blue shape background, now it is invisible, however, it is still there, so, for example if there is a line at the top of an elllipse, I cannot select the ellipse since the invisible line selected area is there and prevents me from doing that. So, is there a way to reduce the selected area to the shape area?