# Change background color of item after visiting

Tags: c#, wpf, xaml

I have the following code:

```
                <ItemsControl Grid.Row="1" ItemsSource="{Binding Activities}">
                    <ItemsControl.ItemsPanel>
                        <ItemsPanelTemplate>
                            <ctrls:AlignableWrapPanel MaxWidth="400" HorizontalContentAlignment="Center"
                                                      HorizontalAlignment="Center" />
                        </ItemsPanelTemplate>
                    </ItemsControl.ItemsPanel>
                    <ItemsControl.ItemContainerStyle>
                        <Style TargetType="ContentPresenter">
                            <Setter Property="HorizontalAlignment" Value="Center" />
                        </Style>
                    </ItemsControl.ItemContainerStyle>
                </ItemsControl>
```

Now I would like to have the background color of each item that has already been clicked on (which leads to a page about the item) changed. On clicking the item again, the background color should change back.

How can I do that?

I have already looked at [Change background color for selected ListBox item](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2138200/change-background-color-for-selected-listbox-item). There is an answer that contains the following code:

```
        <Style TargetType="ListBoxItem">
            <Style.Triggers>
                <Trigger Property="IsSelected" Value="True" >
                    <Setter Property="FontWeight" Value="Bold" />
                    <Setter Property="Background" Value="Transparent" />
                    <Setter Property="Foreground" Value="Black" />
                </Trigger>
            </Style.Triggers>
            <Style.Resources>
                <SolidColorBrush x:Key="{x:Static SystemColors.HighlightBrushKey}" Color="Transparent"/>
            </Style.Resources>
        </Style>
```

Alas, I can't easily insert this code in my code since I am already setting the style for ContentPresenter. Besides, it probably does not do exactly what I want.

Answer (score 0):

You can combine these styles. But there's a catch: overriding `SystemColors.HighlighBrush` won't help you in Windows 8+. Plus, you need to enable multiselect, which is not available for `ItemsControl`, but `ListBox` has it. Try this code:

```
<ListBox ItemsSource="{Binding Activities}" SelectionMode="Multiple">
    <ItemsControl.ItemsPanel>
        <ItemsPanelTemplate>
            <ctrls:AlignableWrapPanel MaxWidth="400" HorizontalContentAlignment="Center" HorizontalAlignment="Center" />
        </ItemsPanelTemplate>
    </ItemsControl.ItemsPanel>
    <ItemsControl.ItemTemplate>
        <DataTemplate>
            <Border>
                <ContentPresenter Content="{Binding}"/>
            </Border>
        </DataTemplate>
    </ItemsControl.ItemTemplate>
    <ItemsControl.ItemContainerStyle>
        <Style TargetType="ListBoxItem">
            <Setter Property="HorizontalAlignment" Value="Center" />
            <Setter Property="Template">
                <Setter.Value>
                    <ControlTemplate TargetType="ListBoxItem">
                        <Border Background="{TemplateBinding Background}">
                            <ContentPresenter Content="{TemplateBinding Content}"/>
                        </Border>
                    </ControlTemplate>
                </Setter.Value>
            </Setter>
            <Style.Triggers>
                <Trigger Property="IsSelected" Value="True" >
                    <Setter Property="FontWeight" Value="Bold" />
                    <Setter Property="Background" Value="Yellow" />
                    <Setter Property="Foreground" Value="Black" />
                </Trigger>
            </Style.Triggers>
        </Style>
    </ItemsControl.ItemContainerStyle>
</ListBox>
```

Answer (score 0):

that code does the trick:

```
<ItemsControl ...>
    ...
    <ItemsControl.Resources>
        <Style TargetType="ToggleButton">
            <Style.Triggers>
                <Trigger Property="IsChecked" Value="True">
                    <Setter Property="Background" Value="Green" />
                </Trigger>
            </Style.Triggers>
        </Style>                
    </ItemsControl.Resources>
    <ItemsControl.ItemTemplate>
        <DataTemplate>
            <ToggleButton Content="{Binding}">
                <ToggleButton.Template>
                    <ControlTemplate>
                        <Label Content="{Binding}" Background="{TemplateBinding Background}" />
                    </ControlTemplate>
                </ToggleButton.Template>
            </ToggleButton>
        </DataTemplate>
    </ItemsControl.ItemTemplate>
</ItemsControl>
```

Answer (score 0):

You can add a property like "IsVisited" to the viewmodel of an item (the item type of "Activities")

Whenever you click on the item, set this property to true/false, e.g. in the same method where you open the details page.

Then, in the DataTemplate of your item, you can create a Datatrigger which binds to the "IsVisited" property, and sets the background color of the item's panel.

Please provide more of your code for more detailed help.