# How to change a listbox unselected item colour from code behind

Tags: c#, wpf, listbox, background-color

I have to create listBox via code behind. After that I have to change the colour that the selected item has when the listbox is not selected.
I have found [that](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2138200/change-background-color-for-selected-listbox-item) solution but am not able to render it via code behind.

[image]

Thank you

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Very easy if it's ok for you overriding the windows colour on the listbox

```
listBox1.Resources[SystemColors.InactiveSelectionHighlightBrushKey] = Brushes.Blue;
```

I picked your rgb colour so to be precise it's:

```
listBox1.Resources[SystemColors.InactiveSelectionHighlightBrushKey] = new SolidColorBrush(Color.FromArgb(255, (byte)51, (byte)153, (byte)255));
```

Answer (score 1):

As you've already seen the answer as in the link, you need to apply a style. Now You need help applying that style (defined in XAML) via code behind? If yes then apply the below code:

```
Style style = this.FindResource("YourStyleName") as Style;
myListBox.Style = style;
```

The above code works if your style is defined in the same Window's XAML. If it's somewhere else, follow the below code:

```
Style style = Application.Current.FindResource("YourStyleName") as Style;
myListBox.Style = style;
```

---

That being said, I would not recommend adding a `listbox` via `C#` as it can be tough to handle UI via C#. I would recommend defining listbox in XAML and using `databinding`, `INotifyPropertyChanged` to reduce your code complexity.

I hope I've answered your question. let me know if there is anything else in the comments section.

Also, please note: in the question the link you've mentioned. exactly like that the style will go in the XAML

Comment: I have no xaml for it's in a plugin defined through appdomain, a dll.

Comment: So what you're saying is that you have no XAML code for the Window you're showing data in? If yes can you share a demo sample solution or some more code through which we can get your issue resolved?